# How to get Cold Keystone?

Tags: tyranny

I got stuck in Tyranny in Oldwalls... to open the force field in the centre I need 3 keystones, I have found two and one that is `Cold keystone` is missing...

[image]

I have now visited all the areas and solved the tower puzzle.... but can't seem to get my hands on `Cold Keystone`

**How to get Cold Keystone?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in the Central Area at the bottom about midway though the map...

To open it you will need one person to click the button (1) on the wall and then with others get into the room that opens set rune to red (2) and the click it(3) ...

[image]

This should open the small room where is the Cold Keystone (4)

Also here's a video